# What to do when function need to be called before script load

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization, openx

I'm calling this function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[
    OA_show(18);
// ]]> --></script>
```

at many sites on a page but the script is loaded at bottom as follow:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//openx.elclarinweb.com/www/delivery/spcjs.php?id=2&#038;target=_blank&#038;ver=20141010'></script>
```

which causes this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: OA_show is not defined
```

**Note**

I can't call the function after script loads because it needs to be called on specific position where Ads will be show, take a look [here](http://elclarinweb.com) to see what I'm talking about

Is there any way to get ride of the error? Should I load the script at top even if it's obtrusive and prevent the page to load before it loads completely? Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put in `onload`:

```
window.onload = function(){
   OA_show(18);
};
```

This waits for all the resources to be loaded and then executes the function you are calling.

Comment: Hi @Jai, this is not working the `OA_show()` function display some image from OpenX server but put in the way you said redirect me to the image

Answer (score 1):

Just call the function at bottom after the `script` loads.

```
...
</body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//openx.elclarinweb.com/www/delivery/spcjs.php?id=2&#038;target=_blank&#038;ver=20141010'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'><!--// <![CDATA[
    OA_show(18);
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Then do `window.onload = OA_show(18);`

Comment: I can't because the function needs to be called on specific position where Ads will be show, take a look [here](http://elclarinweb.com) to see what I'm talking about

Comment: Should have said that in your original question.

Comment: @JeremyThille added on main post, my bad